# Resize image - keep ratio - without background image

Tags: html, wordpress, image, css

Im trying to achieve the effect shown on this site:

http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/scale-img/target-ratio-resize.htm

BUT this site does it using a background image for a div. I cannot use the background image as the image is inside Wordpress and it's being brought in dynamically using the following code:

```
<div class="featured-image">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
```

So I have tried the same approach and tried the following things o try and bring the image in as a background image:

```
.featured-image {
  max-width: 960px;
  /* actual img width */
  max-height: 150px;
  /* actual img height */*
  height: 150px;
  /* actual img height - IE7 */
  background-image: <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

and using this:

```
background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>);
```

Alas, I cant seem to get it to work - Im not even sure I can use PHP inside a CSS document...

So I'm looking for a way to achieve this image resize just on the following class without using a background image...

```
<div class="featured-image">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated - I don't even know if I'm thinking about it correctly or I'm missing something - Thanks!

Example of what I'm trying to achieve here:

[image]

Comment: Inside the div. What displays in the DOM after <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> runs?

Comment: <div class="featured-image">
        <img width="3200" height="1000" src="http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/house.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/house.jpg 3200w, http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/house-300x94.jpg 300w, http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/house-768x240.jpg 768w, http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/house-700x219.jpg 700w" sizes="(max-width: 3200px) 100vw, 3200px"></div>

Comment: Not 100% sure what the DOM is - but it outputs to that:

Comment: Exactly what I needed to see :) That is a HUGE image though. I'll try and figure something out with an IMG tag inside a DIV. DOM laymen term, basically the source code of your page. Actually, its a bit more than that. Won't hurt to read up on it. Will help you understand HTML more too. It helped me anyway.

Comment: I definitely will investigate the DOM! :) Thanks

Comment: Would you mind using jquery. If you're using wordpress, it should be okay

Comment: No, Im happy to use jQuery - whatever works really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably an easier way, But using Jquery does the trick. Don't think you really need my CSS, apart from the position:relative for the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/ny746vLx/2/ (Non WordPress)

Jquery as follows:

```
$(".featured-image>img").each(function(i, img) {
    $(img).css({
        left: ($(img).parent().width() - $(img).width()) / 2
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ny746vLx/4/ (Wordpress)

```
;(function($){
    imageChange = function(){
        $(".featured-image>img").each(function(i, img) {
        $(img).css({
            left: ($(img).parent().width() - $(img).width()) / 2
        });
    });
}
    $(window).resize(imageChange); 
})(jQuery);

imageChange();
```

This will physically move the image to the left enough for the image to center.

The jQuery selector '>' means that it will target all img tags directly after the .imageContainer div. You can use these declarations in your CSS too.

EDIT: I've used the classes that you've printed above. Don't think you'll need to change anything from the fiddle. Just remember to add position:relative to your css for the image.

EDIT2: I've added another fiddle that will work (Hopefully) with wordpress. jQuery has some conflicts with it. There are easier ways but I'm unfamiliar really with conflicts in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Gezzasa - Ill give it a shot and see if it works for me

Comment: Hi - This doesn't seem to actually work I'm afraid - Here's what i'm getting: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/theatre/get-creative/exhibit/ it still shrinks the height of the image and the edges are still stuck to the edge... The main thing is to make sure the image is larger (height) than it currently is on mobile :) Ive updated my question with a screen mockup too

Comment: It works :). Normal jQuery conflicts with WordPress. Fixed the code in the second fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using Bootstrap,don't use the image as background but use it as with the proper `<img> tag` and add `img-fluid` and `d-block` class to image tag.

Comment: I am using bootstrap! I will give this a go :)

Comment: let me know the output.

Comment: Ive tried this and it doesnt seem to work - heres the page its outputting on http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/youth-community/support-us/sponsor-a-house/

Comment: It looks fine for me. It is resizing to correctly without any issues. Try clearing yorur cache and refresh the page.

Comment: It's not working the way the example I provided is working

Comment: You mean like zoom in when the screen goes small?

Comment: Essentially im looking to make the taller on mobile devices - so I would like it to bleed out of the edge and stick to a height of 250px - instead the edges don't bleed out of the side and it shrinks down to far too small

Comment: Check your code you have two <img> tags and the tag which has the `d-block` is empty.

Comment: http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/scale-img/target-ratio-resize.htm if you look here their image stays the same height but when it shrinks the left and right edge move outside of the container box

Comment: Here's what Im using: <div class="featured-image">
        <img class="img-fluid d-block"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><img>
      </div>

Answer (score 1):

To create the desired effect, they gave a `padding-top` property to the `background-image` wrapper class. And restricted the image to a `max-height` so, it doesn't grow bigger than that. Rest was all CSS.

As you wanted it to be **dynamic** `image`, now you can change the `style` tag value using your backend code

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 150px;
  /* restricted image height */
}

.section:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 33.333%;
  /* this is not as per formula, but as a custom aspect ratio */
}
```

```html
<div class="section" style="background-image: url('http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/scale-img/students.jpg')">


</div>

<h1>When you want to keep the aspect ratio in background images use below formula</h1>
<code>((image height * 100%) / image width)</code>
```

Comment: I can see how they did it - but this wont work because I need the image (image url) to be dynamic.

Comment: give your image tag in `style` tag. I'll modify my code for you

Answer (score 0):

Try using inline `CSS` to achieve it in your `HTML` template like this:

```php
<div 
    class="featured-image" 
    style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>);">
</div>
```

Then use `CSS` to display the `image` properly:

```css
.featured-image{
   display:inline-block; /** or block, whichever suits your design **/
   background-size:cover;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

With this approach, you can even have more elements display on the image within the "featured-image" div.

I've just updated this answer to output the post thumbnail `url` rather than with the default `img` tag.

Comment: The image coming from the PHP is inside of an img tag. Don't think this will work.

Comment: yeah I just tried it and this bit doesnt work: background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>); it was my first thought though too!

Comment: My bad, I've just updated the code to output the image url rather than with the img tag see the section with: `the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full');`

Comment: Hi - thanks for altering - however I still cant appear to get: background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>); working - its nt pulling through any image I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be get_the_post_thumbnail_url.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="featured-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('full');?>);"></div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

.featured-image {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```